# Windows API поиск файла по расширению и запись в строку или как конвертировать HANDLE в строку

Tags: c++, c, windows

Ну значит я хочу скопировать фоновое изображение пользователя, записать его название и скопировать в другую папку, но как мне найти это фото по расширению, так как одного имени он не имеет.

```
        WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        HANDLE hFind;

        std::string bg(getenv("APPDATA"));
        bg.append("\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Themes\\\\CachedFiles\\\\*.jpg");

        hFind = (FindFirstFile(bg.c_str(), &FindFileData));

        //path = hFind.c_str();

        std::string game(_getcwd(NULL, 0));
        game.append("\\\\assets\\\\images\\\\backgrounds\\\\yourBG.jpg");
        
        CopyFile(hFind.c_str(), game.c_str(), FALSE);
```

Тут я указываю папку с файлом и пытаюсь провести поиск по расширению, но при попытке конвертирова HANDLE в строку мне выводит ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо имя смотреть в FindFileData, а hFind нужен для дальнейшего поиска FindNextFile

```
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATA {
  DWORD     dwFileAttributes; 
  FILETIME  ftCreationTime; 
  FILETIME  ftLastAccessTime; 
  FILETIME  ftLastWriteTime; 
  DWORD     nFileSizeHigh; 
  DWORD     nFileSizeLow; 
  DWORD     dwReserved0; 
  DWORD     dwReserved1; 
  TCHAR     cFileName[ MAX_PATH ]; 
  TCHAR     cAlternateFileName[ 14 ]; 
} WIN32_FIND_DATA, *PWIN32_FIND_DATA;
```

Пример поиска:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream.h"

void main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf=FindFirstFile("c:\\*", &FindFileData);
    if (hf!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hf,&FindFileData)!=0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное я сделал что то не так, но после изменения последней строки на:

`CopyFile(FindFileData.c_str(), game.c_str(), FALSE);`

Мне выдает ошибку

`"c_str": не является членом "_WIN32_FIND_DATAA".`

Comment: CopyFile(FindFileData.cFileName, game.c_str(), FALSE);

Comment: FindFileData - это структура и вней уже элементы

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает